# How to get union of 2 lists of dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, arrays

I have 2 lists with the following data structure:

```
 array1:
 [{'student': {'name': 'abc'}, 'address': 'add_abc'}, 
  {'student': {'name': 'xyz'},  'address': 'add_xyz'}]

 array2:
 [{'student': {'name': 'abc'}, 'address': 'add_abc'}, 
  {'student': {'name': 'rst'},  'address': 'add_rst'}]
```

I want to have an `array3` with union of the above 2 lists

```
 array3:
 [{'student': {'name': 'abc'}, 'address': 'add_abc'}, 
  {'student': {'name': 'rst'},  'address': 'add_rst'},
  {'student': {'name': 'xyz'},  'address': 'add_xyz'}]
```

How can I do that in Python?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are `lists`, not arrays, but here is a solution:

```
a1 = [{'student': {'name': 'abc'}, 'address': 'add_abc'}, 
      {'student': {'name': 'xyz'},  'address': 'add_xyz'}]
a2 = [{'student': {'name': 'abc'}, 'address': 'add_abc'},  
      {'student': {'name': 'rst'},  'address': 'add_rst'}]
a3 = a1 + [i for i in a2 if i not in a1]
```

the value of `a3` will be

```
[{'student': {'name': 'abc'}, 'address': 'add_abc'}, 
 {'student': {'name': 'xyz'}, 'address': 'add_xyz'}, 
 {'student': {'name': 'rst'}, 'address': 'add_rst'}]
```

If you want your resulting list to be sorted (by student name, for example), simply use `sort` method:

```
a3.sort(key=lambda x: x["student"]["name"])
```

and the resulting `a3` would be:

```
[{'student': {'name': 'abc'}, 'address': 'add_abc'}, 
 {'student': {'name': 'rst'}, 'address': 'add_rst'},
 {'student': {'name': 'xyz'}, 'address': 'add_xyz'}]
```

Normally you would simply use `set(a1 + a2)` but the problem here is that you have `dict`s inside your `list`s and they are unhashable, therefore they cannot be set items.